# rsync is missing files

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, rsync

I'm trying to get rsync working between Win7/cygwin source and CentOS 7 VM destination.

My command:

`rsync --dry-run -r -a -v -i -h -x --ignore-times --checksum --progress --delete --delete-before --force /cygdrive/path/to/local user@sshhost.com:/path/to/remote`

There are files in within the local directory tree that **do not exist** on the remote side, yet I get no files listed for transfer when I run this command.

I have key auth SSH access configured and rsync is installed on the remote machine.

What am I missing?

Comment: are the files hidden on either side (source or destination)?  I assume the `-h` address that (I haven't read the man yet) but it may not be reading things correctly for whatever reason

Comment: Yeah, I think that was it.  I changed paths to `/path/to/whatever/.` <-- *the dot on the end.*